# Determine if value exists in table, If not? then add value

Tags: vba, ms-access

G'day Team

First time poster.

Kind of hoping you can assist in tweaking the below code.

So! onto the premise.

User enters Master Account # + Location ID # (2 = Primary Address Location, 3 upward = secondary, tertiary and so-on locations); this generates the [Location #, which is their Unique Key]

Generic information is then entered (Name, Address, etc).

User then clicks on a cmdBtn that opens up another form which is where the customer's Route & Sequencing information is stored. [this is where my problem lies]!

I tried the following (sampled from a google search, modified):

```
Private Sub cmdBtnRoute_Click()

    Const fName = "fDRout"
    Dim strCriteria As String

    strCriteria = "[lnLocNo]= " & Me.lnLocNo

    If Not IsNull(Me.lnLocNo) Then                                                     
        Me.Dirty = False                                                                
        DoCmd.OpenForm fName, , "", strCriteria, , acDialog, lnLocNo.Value
        Else
        DoCmd.OpenForm fName, , , , , acDialog
    End If

 End Sub
```

So! essentially what I would like it to do is; determine when [fDRout] opens:

Does Me.lnLocNo.Value exist:
Yes:. Display the form (It will open with the matching Location # record).
No:.. Display the form (Pass Me.lnLocNo.Value to the new record field).

TIA
Mark.

Comment: What is the exact error message displayed when the VBA code does not work?

Comment: Hi BraX, I appreciate your time. No error message. Just a blank field.

It's all good though. A result was provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *OnOpen* event of your *fDrout* form to set the *default value* of *lnLocNo*:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Me!lnLocNo.DefaultValue = "" & Me.OpenArgs & ""
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

End Sub
```

Comment: G'day Gustav. Appreciate the response. Won't this trigger a new record each time fDRout is opened??

Comment: This is the kind of question I never learn to understand. Why don't you try? In less than one minute you will have the answer - way faster than waiting for a response.

Comment: Oh, Wow! Just what a newbie poster needs; condescension.